# Install Ubuntu12.04(LTS)

Tags: 12.04, 11.04, upgrade

I have a ubuntu 11.04 in my laptop but it is now not supported, Now I want to install ubuntu 12.04.
For this I have download the .iso file of the ubuntu 12.04. But my update manager recommend me to install 11.10.
So Can I install ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: You can't skip releases if you're updating through the Update Manager, boot the 12.04 ISO and upgrade.

Comment: yes I want to update from the boot cd......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you can't exactly skip OS's from the Update Manager. So you have to boot from a Ubuntu 12.04 ISO file (Via a CD, for example.).

These are the ways to install the ISO:

[Live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-dvd-on-windows): Follow the steps!

[USB installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) Again, follow the steps!

[Stand-Alone Installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop): Install then follow the steps!

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can easily install 12.04 from scratch.

Mind you: 12.04.2 is out and I'd like to suggest that you download and install this version. It has all released updates inside the ISO + has a newer kernel (3.5) and X-server.

I wouldn't go for an **upgrade** since the changes are severe compared to 11.04.

Keep in mind with the required hardware specifications ! Having for about 1.5 Gb RAM-memory is certainly nessecary for a good work-flow (my own standards).

If you have less RAM I'd go for Xubuntu, what will run far better than Ubuntu (Unity).